# PHP rawurldecode does not decode single ticks

Tags: javascript, php, decode, encode

Since the escape function is deprecated, I created this function as it is used throughout my website and it would be tedious to replace every occurence.

```
function escape(text) {
    text = text.replace(/'/g, "%27");
    return encodeURI(text);
}
```

This changes a string such as `This is Ben's bookcase` into `This%20is%20Ben%2527s%20Bookcase`.

When I try to decode this in PHP, using [rawurldecode()](http://php.net/rawurldecode), I end up with this `This is 
Ben%27s Bookcase`.

How can I make urldecode in PHP decode single ticks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing it wrong.

The original character `'` is turned into `%27`, and then the percent sign is turned into `%25`. This second step must not happen.

If you want to encode everything else, and then also single quotes, first call `encodeURI`, then replace.

That way, `'` will return unaltered from escaping, and then be transformed into `%27`, with no further changes.

PHP can then decode the string properly.